# Phone_State in ADB

Tags: android, adb, telephonymanager

I am trying to track any incoming/Outgoing calls on my Android phone using ADB. I see that you can use Phone_state from Telephony Manager to track what is the state of the telephone in an app. How can I do this from ADB?

Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 1):

```
dumpsys telephony.registry | grep mCallState=
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
  adb logcat
```

And check what is happening in the backend of the phone.

Comment: Also, sometimes, the `adb logcat` session dies, why is that?